# How to convert a response from KSQL - UDF returning JSON array to columns

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a custom UDF called getCityStats(string city, double distance) which takes 2 arguments and returns an array of JSON strings ( Objects) as follows

> ```
> {"zipCode":"90921","mode":3.54}
> {"zipCode":"91029","mode":7.23}
> {"zipCode":"96928","mode":4.56} 
> {"zipCode":"90921","mode":6.54}
> {"zipCode":"91029","mode":4.43}
> {"zipCode":"96928","mode":3.96}
> ```

I would like to process them in a KSQL table creation query as

```
create table city_stats
as
select 
 zipCode,
 avg(mode) as mode
from 
 (select 
     getCityStats(city,distance) as (zipCode,mode)
  from 
     city_data_stream
 ) t 
group by zipCode;
```

In other words can KSQL handle tuple type where an array of Json strings can be processed to return as indicated above in a table creation query?

Answer (score 0):

No, KSQL doesn't currently support the syntax you're suggesting. Whilst KSQL can work with arrays, it doesn't get support any kind of explode function, so you can reference specific index points in the array only.

Feel free to view and upvote if appropriate these issues: [#527](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/527), [#1830](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1830), or indeed [raise your own](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new) if they don't cover what you want to do.